# Include HTML file in another HTML file WITHOUT server. Is that Possible?

Tags: html, include, ssi

I am having a header which it will be uniform in all the pages. I want to make it generic. So I want to include common header in every HTML Page.

When i checked for HTML includes i cameup with SSI which needs a server. My Requirement is I want to include HTML file in another WITHOUT a server.

Comment: Please explain the use case. Unless you're serving the files locally (using `file//`) you'll need a server.

Comment: people want to do quick dev testing without a server and it is very convenient to be able to do html includes without a server.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do it would be to make a "hanger" `div` with a class of `.header`. Then put a `<p>` inside the `div` to put `alt` text into. Then in your main css stylesheet apply your header image as a background image, and negatively indent the text.

```
Example
.hanger {background-image:url(header.png); text-indent:-1000px;}
```

To resize the header all you would do is put a width and height on `div.hanger`.

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of including html in another html file. I think what you can trying to do can be accomplished using an iframe.

example: header.html

Answer (score 0):

[This later question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file) got an answer that works with files on disk provided you are using firefox.

Chrome gives a cross site scripting error

Answer (score -1):

You could have a `<div>` for the header, I will call it `<div id="header">`.
Using jQuery we could say something like: `$('#header').load(---html file---);`.  Aside from the pain it might be to include the JS file in all pages, it will allow you to make changes to the header globally throughout your application.

Comment: the load() command will fail iwthout a server.